# How to unstruct a Struct in SQL

Tags: sql, apache-iceberg

I have a struct in a table (`Iceberg Database` format) and I would like to expand all of the children of the struct.

The normal query would look like :

```
SELECT 
  base.el1, 
  base.el2, 
  base.el3 
FROM myTable
```

Instead of that, I would like to have a statement as the following: (not working - just an idea)

```
Select 
  base.* 
FROM myTable
```

That would return

| el1 | el2 | el3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three |

Is it possible to realize such statement?
In real-life I have like hundreds of elements and do not wish write all of them down.

If I do the proposed (not-working) statement.
It returns something like:

| col1 |
| --- |
| (One,Two,Three) |

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to concatenate the columns like this?

```
select concat(el1,',',el2,',',el3) as b from a;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cqusK23oVYcTBvD4cv9GoA/0

Comment: No. 
I would like to do the inverse of concat, in a way. A column per value.

Comment: oh I see. It would be helpful if you could provide sample data and the table definition; I have not worked with ICEBERG before but I'm sure we can figure out the SQL to do what you need

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it just works with the following statement:

```
Select 
  base.* 
FROM myTable
```

For some reason it was returning an erroronous result but not from my part of the Query statement.